# Chilton 240SX repair manual : washer nozzle adjustment

Tags: windshield-washer

I own the Chilton Repair manual for the nissan 240 SX :
[image]

In it there is a figure about how to adjust a washer nozzle :
[image]

What is this tool? Can I get it? And how else can I safely adjust the nozzle?

My nozzle looks like this if it matters:
[image]

Comment: That's a brute force way to do an adjustment!  Use a safety pin like everyone else.